# Как дать Label-у имя, используя код?

Tags: java, swing

Можно ли в java переименовать `Label`, прописав это в коде самостоятельно?

Допустим, создали объект `Label label_2 = new JLabel("");`, а нужно переименовать ее, например, в `l1`.

Comment: покажите, как именно Вы создаете "метку".

Comment: Попробуйте более полно и точно сформулировать свой вопрос, ибо мне кажется, что под меткой Вы имеете ввиду что-то отличное от общепринятого в Java значения этого термина.

Comment: label_2 = new JLabel("");

Comment: @arthurasche, И что Вы хотите здесь поменять?

Comment: думаю, человек хочет помнять label_2  на l1

Comment: имя метки. ну, чтобы не Label_2 было, а как-нибудь по-иному.

Comment: зачем  вы хотите это сделать? что вы хотите этим достичь?

Comment: Ну так поменяйте. Напишите `JLabel l1 = new JLabel("");`

Comment: это же вроде просто новая метка создастся, нет?

Comment: А чем мешает  
label_2 = new JLabel(""); почему её надо переименовать?

Comment: м, действительно, сглупил. спасибо всем за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

Если переменную уже создали, то поменять ее название нельзя.
( Если имеется введу в процессе исполнения кода )
Даже по логике Java это сделать нельзя, ибо таких функций нету.
Максимум что ты можешь сделать это сделать 'вторую' переменную, со значением 1-ой.

```
// Допустим первая переменная назвыаеться label_2
JLabel l1 = label_2; // Я не уверен что это будет работать с JLabel'ами, но все-же

//Если хочешь обновления переменной ( допустим время таймера )
//То закинь в цикл
boolean x = true; 
while(x = true) {
   l1 = label_2;
}
```

Помог чем смог)

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: Забыл добавить JLabel перед l1 :|

Comment: @RED, под ответом есть кнопка `править`

Comment: Код с циклом - лучше удалить. Это жесть какая-то)

Answer (score 0):

```
JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("");
```

Если вы хотите сменить текст в метке, можно, во первых, создать её с нужным текстом:

```
JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("Initial text");
```

Во вторых, у `JLabel` есть метод [setText(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setText(java.lang.String)), чтобы сменить текст позже:

```
label_2.setText("New text");
```